# Generation of random float number within -1 and 1 produces NaNs

Tags: java, random, floating-point

I need to generate floats within a range of -1 and 1. I'm using this line:

```
 weights[i] = random.nextFloat() * (weightMax - weightMin) + weightMin;
```

where `weightMax = 1` and `weightMin = -1`

but occasionally it produces NaNs. How can I prevent that from happening?

EDIT:
Yes, you are right. I am later doing this:

```
private void run_neural_network(double[] inputs, double[] outputs) {
    int i, j;
    int weight_counter = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < NB_OUTPUTS; i++) {
        double sum = 0.0;
        for (j = 0; j < NB_INPUTS; j++) {
            sum += inputs[j] * weights[weight_counter];
            weight_counter++;
        }
        outputs[i] = (Math.tanh(sum + weights[weight_counter]));
        weight_counter++;
    }
}
```

And it is the `sum` that is the source of NaN:

```
[EpuckController] inputs0: 0.0, weight0 0.06174159,
[EpuckController] inputs1: 306.1555543759677, weight1 -7.409203E-23,
[EpuckController] inputs2: 0.0, weight2 1.2461361E-29,
[EpuckController] inputs3: 307.56460985278545, weight3 194105.33,
[EpuckController] inputs4: 0.0, weight4 0.41100776,
[EpuckController] inputs5: 0.0, weight5 0.0013858302,
[EpuckController] inputs6: 320.0046791338875, weight6 -1.49799987E14,
[EpuckController] inputs7: 0.0, weight7 195593.81,
[EpuckController] inputs8: 421.5353365457416, weight8 -0.8191289,
[EpuckController] Sum NaN
```

Comment: Are you doing other manipulations on the weights array? I can't see any flaw in the code you posted.

Answer (score 3):

I strongly suspect the NaN is coming from elsewhere - e.g. due to a division operation on the weights later.

While it's certainly not proof, I've created a billion floats and not seen the behaviour you've suggested:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random random = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++) {
            float f = random.nextFloat() * 2 - 1;
            if (Float.isNaN(f)) {
                System.out.println("NaN!");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

(And of course it doesn't make *sense* that the code you've provided would generate a NaN.)

I suggest you add a `Float.isNaN` test immediately after your array assignment. If you *don't* see it then, but you *do* see it later, then clearly the problem is with something you're doing with the weights, rather than the weights themselves.

Comment: Sorry for writing this comment here but you wrote C# in Depth? Respect!

Comment: Yes, you're right. I edited initial post and added the source of NaNs.